# Paypal-Merchant-SDK : How get only token using the SetExpressCheckout.php and then passe it to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Please can anyone explain to me step by step cause i'm so confused about the example that Paypal give us, the "SetExpressCheckout.php", it contains a lot of stuff, i want only to generate a token so i can create a Recurring Payments Profile using "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php"

Please help, i have read some tutorials but never showed from the beginning how to start to create a subscription or Recurring Payments.

I'm using the Merchant-SDK-PHP : https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php

Just in case someone want to know why i want to use Paypal's classic API, it's because the REST API does not have an option to hide the shipping address when creating a *subscription*, and Web Experience cannot be attached to a plan or an agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confusing because when you are in the samples pages, there's no where you can find what you should do after getting the token using SetExpressCheckOut.php.

So to pass the token to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php, at the end of SetExpressCheckOut.php you need to redirect the costumer to > https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token

Where the $token is the Token you got in SetExpressCheckOut.php using :

```
$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
$token = $setECResponse->Token;
```

Before redirecting make sure (in your SetExpressCheckOut.php) `$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL` refers to the link that will trigger CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php

In my case i'm using Laravel
`$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = "domain.com/createsub"`
And my route is : `Route::get('createsub', 'PaypalContoller@CreateRecurringPayments')`
So within the CreateRecurringPayments method i put all the stuff from CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php example.

Note : when you go live you need to remove sandbox from the link : > https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token